# How to use ES6 features when writing server-side JavaScript without Babel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

There [are](https://blog.logrocket.com/you-dont-need-babel-with-node/) [many](https://www.getrevue.co/profile/masteringjs/issues/mastering-js-do-you-really-need-babel-anymore-179610) [articles](https://dev.to/dandv/why-you-dont-really-need-babel-4k2h) these days that claim you don't need Babel anymore when developing Node apps while leveraging the features of ES6.
Since I plan to write a terminal app using Node, I have some practical questions.

1. Is there some consensus in the JS community on which is the minimum required Node version for this?
   If so, does this version support all of the ES6 standard or only parts of it?
   *Edit: To be more precise -- was there a version X that featured ES6 well enough that it caused the majority of devs to omit Babel?*
2. Is there a chance to guard your app from being executed (or rather failing to be executed) with an older version of Node? *Edit: To be more precise -- I plan to write a terminal app, so I have no control over the Node version that people will have installed on their machine (on which they will try to run my app on).*
3. Is there a cool terminal app based on Node and ES6 that I can study for best practices? Any recommendations?

Comment: "*Is there some consensus in the JS community on which is the minimum required Node version for this?*" why would the JS community have to have a consensus? The engine either supports ES6 or doesn't - there are specs you can check for that.

Comment: "*Is there a chance to guard your app from being executed (or rather failing to be executed) with an older version of Node?*" just write the requirements as "has to be run at version X or later". If somebody runs it with an earlier one - they'd get errors. Or just have a small check and bomb out with an "Unsupported version error" of some sort early.

Comment: You don’t need Babel if you’re using *any* supported version of Node. (You might miss out on some post-ES6 features in older versions, but they’re not worth introducing Babel for. Then again, I’ve always thought that about Babel, so maybe others disagree.) And since nobody should be using an unsupported version of Node, you can target Node 10 (Node 8 just reached EOL) and reasonably skip a version check.

Comment: "*Is there a cool terminal app based on Node and ES6 that I can study for best practices? Any recommendations?*" asking for off-site recommendations is off-topic for SO and I think you've been around to know that. Speaking of, multiple questions are also off-topic.

Comment: Check out https://node.green/ . v10.18 which was the previous LTS release supports all ES6 features (except tail call optimization and modules).

Answer (score 0):

12.14.0 doesn't support ES6 modules well enough that I would recommend using them without a transpiler.

I understand that 13.5.0 will allow you to use native ES6 modules without experimental flags, but its not a stable LTS release.

14.0.0 is the first release I'd attempt using native ES6 modules without a transpiler. However, it is not yet released. I like how [Deno](https://deno.land/) provides native ES6 support without NPM, but it is still a beta software.

Answer (score -1):

From https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/
*Node.js is built against modern versions of V8. By keeping up-to-date with the latest releases of this engine, we ensure new features from the JavaScript ECMA-262 specification are brought to Node.js developers in a timely manner, as well as continued performance and stability improvements.*

Checkout out the following to see all fully supported features
https://node.green/

Answer (score -2):

To begin, I really recommend using the latest available LTS version of Node.js, which, at the moment is `12.14.0`.

But, if for some reason or another you plan to use an older version, you can check out ES6 support [here](https://node.green/).

Anyway, if you want to use some post-ES6 features you really should be using `babel`.